# Applying CSS to Dynamically Named Polymer Elements

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

We have been having a discussion around getting Polymer components on NPM and part of the context is that it would be nice if the end result worked well with transitive component dependencies.  Here's the discussion link along with one possible solution suggested by Rob Dodson / Domenic Denicola [Publish sub-projects on npm, add them to package.json](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/326#issuecomment-231922469)

This suggest leaving the registration of the element up to the developer such that the developer can avoid element registration collisions.  We could write a Polymer like element registration wrapper that:

- Recompiles transitive dependency modules with a new element name
- Registers the element with the new element name in the browser
- Kisses Bower goodbye and lives happily ever after

So the next question is how would CSS be impacted by this?  Here's an example from [Shadow DOM v1: self-contained web components](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/shadowdom/)
 that uses a custom element `fancy-tabs` selector:

### Main Page

```
<style>
  fancy-tabs {
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    --fancy-tabs-bg: black;
  }
</style>
<fancy-tabs background>...</fancy-tabs>
```

### CSS Shadow Dom Implementation:

```
:host([background]) {
  background: var(--fancy-tabs-bg, #9E9E9E);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

So if custom elements are used as variable container in the main page to style components that are transitive dependencies, then we run into a problem due to component renaming.  Is there a way around this?  For example say using a `.fancy-tabs` selector.

Can anyone think of any other issues outside of CSS that may occur as a result of trying this approach?

TIA,
Ole

Comment: I added an issue here [Rapid prototyping with transitive NPM dependency element resolution](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3875) to track progress on this and related issues.  Instead of dynamically changing the tag name in the browser we could generate a bower like flat dependency layout and recompile transitive dependency conflicts.